# Is there a maximum score on Flick Kick Football Legends?

Tags: football-legends

I've been playing this game for a while now and it seems to me that there is a limit of how many goals can be scored during a match. The maximum I've got was a 6x0, playing with my best team on the easiest league possible. Is that the maximum possible?

[image]

Comment: Are the pictures really necessary?  I'm not seeing anything in them that really adds to your question.

Comment: @Frank I guess the second one was unnecessary...